# Smartphone access to internet via Windows 8 soft-AP and also access to VM guest server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, wireless-bridge

I want to achieve that my smartphone has Internet-access and can, at the same time, access an apache/webserver that runs in a VM.

Setup:

Windows 8 laptop connected to our compary network via Ethernet-cable (internal IP: 129.26...). This connection provides Internet-access and the IP is provided by the company's DHCP server automatically. Using Windows 8 built-in methods, I turned the WiFi-module of that laptop to serve as hotspot, as described [here](http://www.talkofweb.com/creating-wi-fi-hotspot-in-windows-8-share-laptop-internet-connection/). This way, my smartphone can access the internet via this hotspot-provided WiFi network.

On that same windows 8 machine I have VirtualBox installed, running an Ubuntu VM. This guest OS runs a webserver. Using either the "bridged" or "host only" modes of VirtualBox, this allows me to access that webserver from the Windows 8 laptop. However, I'm still unable to access the webserver from the smartphone via WIFI. How do I achieve that?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

in your case forget about NAT and try bridging in the VM Devices menu switch the Network device to the Wi-Fi adapter and see if it works

Comment: Already tried that. Didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: what part didn't work? you lost internet from your smartphone or you couldn't reach your HTTP server from it or both?

Comment: It turns out that the more likely reason for it to fail is that I should haev set the bridging network device to the NIC (that connects me to my company network). However, that doesn't work because our company's DHCP-server only accepts those NICs with MAC addresses that are known to the system, and the VM's virtual NIC isn't.